# how to make read only filesystem writable on busybox?

Tags: filesystems, busybox, router, squashfs, mips

I want to change some files on my router. Firstly i can change everything in /var, but i want to change /etc/fstab. when i try to change it, i get an error message that says filesystem is read only.

Busybox inside router, has limited commands, so i had got busybox binary for mips http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.19.0/busybox-mips, and upload it by tftp (`tftp -g -r busybox-mips my.i.p.addr`), so now i can use full commands (`/var/tmp/busybox-mips` command).

There is no rom inside router (sdram), or there is no another partition. it must be related with busybox.

```
# /var/tmp/busybox-mips df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 1344      1344         0 100% /

# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
/dev/root on / type squashfs (ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nodiratime)
ramfs on /var type ramfs (rw)
# 



Model: 
        Airties 5021
Processor:
        BCM6332KFBG
        HS1037 P12
        994981 N1
Memory: 
        M12L64164A-7T (SDRAM)
        ANM1P02HL 1028
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't related to BusyBox. BusyBox is a set of unix utilities designed for low-resource environments such as routers. Your router's root filesystem is mounted read-only because it's stored on [SquashFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS), a compressed filesystem which cannot be written to. A SquashFS filesystem is compressed in one go when the filesystem is built and cannot be modified afterwards.

Such routers generally run a variant or derivative of [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT). Most variants have another filesystem on the side, usually [JFFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFFS2), which is writable. It looks like yours is completely locked down. Check if there's an option somewhere to “unlock” an extra filesystem (it could be an option in [NVRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVRAM) that you can set through the web interface, or with the `nvram` utility if you have one). If you don't find a way in, consider installing an alternate firmware, such as [OpenWRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWRT), [DD-WRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DD-WRT), [Tomato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_%28firmware%29), … (check that your particular router model is supported before starting the installation).

Answer (score 0):

use unionfs and create some small MB size partition and 
with unionfs attached both partition and make r/o partition also r/w